# Jenkins File with Sonar integration

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

I am writing a Jenkins multibranch pipeline script in which I want to integrate sonar scan.
My Quality analysis phase goes like this:

```
stage ('Quality Analysis')
    {
withMaven(".......") 
    {
    withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') {
          sh " cd  $project_path; mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=abc -Dsonar.projectKey=xyz -Dsonar.projectName=xyz -Dsonar.java.binaries=*/target/classes -Dsonar.sources=src/main/java/** -Dsonar.exclusions=src/test/java/** -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=ISO-8859-1 -Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview"                } 
    }
```

My analysis phase is running correctly , but there are no issue coming in report after scan, I think the code is not getting scanned . Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solve it by placing the path where the EAR is to the following environment variable:

```
-Dsonar.java.libraries = ../PathProjectEar/target/nameProject.ear
```

The command is as follows:

```
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -f PathProjectParent/pom.xml -Dsonar.java.libraries=../PathProjectEar/target/nameProject.ear
```